# How to prove if $5/2 < x < (5/4)(1+\sqrt2)$, then $25/(x(2x-5)\ge 8$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, formal-proofs

if $\frac52 < x < \frac54(1+\sqrt2)$, then $\frac{25}{x(2x-5)} \ge 8$

First I unpacked the conclusion to:

$$ 16w^2-40w-25 \le 0 $$

I attempted to solve by manipulating the interval (squaring, multiplying):

$$100 \lt 16w^2 ≤25(3+2\sqrt2) $$

$$-50(1+\sqrt2)≤-40w <-100 $$

Then I added the inequalities and subtracted 25.

$$ 50-50\sqrt2-25<16w^2-40w-25<-25+50\sqrt2-25 $$

but that give me

$$ 16w^2-40w-25 \lt 50(\sqrt2-1) $$
which is not $ 16w^2-40w-25 \le 0 $

what did I do wrong?

(there is another interval that i already proved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac52 < x < \frac54(1+\sqrt2), then \frac{25}{x(2x-5)} \ge 8
$

The conclusion is
the same as
$x(2x-5) 
\le 25/8
$
(since $x > 5/2$)

or
$4x^2-10x
\le 25/4
$

or
$(2x-5/2)^2-25/4
\le 25/4
$

or
$(2x-5/2)^2-25/4
\le 25/4
$

or
$(2x-5/2)^2
\le 25/2
$

or
$|2x-5/2|
\le 5/\sqrt{2}
=5\sqrt{2}/2
$

or
$-5\sqrt{2}/2
\le 2x-5/2
\le 5\sqrt{2}/2
$

or
$5/2-5\sqrt{2}/2
\le 2x
\le 5/2+5\sqrt{2}/2
$

or
$5/4-5\sqrt{2}/4
\le x
\le 5/4+5\sqrt{2}/2
$

or
$5/4(1-\sqrt{2})
\le x
\le 5/4(1+\sqrt{2})
$

and these are implied
by the hypotheses.

Comment: thank you! so that means i will just have to work from bottom up to the conclusion.

Comment: It depends on the problem. Of course, if this hadn't worked, I wouldn't have submitted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from your unpacked conclusion:

Let $f$ be the polynomial

$f(w) = 16w - 40w -25 $, with roots:

$$ w = \frac{5}{4}(1 \pm \sqrt 2)$$.

[image]

$f$ obtains negative values between the roots, i.e. in the interval $\left(\>\frac 5 4 (1 - \sqrt 2), \frac 5 4 (1 + \sqrt 2) \> \right)$.

As 
$$\left( \frac 5 2, \frac 5 4 (1 + \sqrt 2) \right) \subset \left(\>\frac 5 4 (1 - \sqrt 2), \frac 5 4 (1 + \sqrt 2) \> \right)$$

the conclusion follows.

Comment: i have to formally prove this algebraically